# Как добавить разделитель между пунктами после сортировки?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть список задач. У каждой из них в вёрстке есть атрибут `data-is_done` со значением `1` или `0`, где `1` — это выполненное, а `0` — еще нет. Выполненные задачи после пузырька сползают вниз, там все хорошо.

```html
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="0"></div>
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="0"></div>
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="1"></div>
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="1"></div>
```

Как мне во время сортировки между пунктами со значением `0` и `1` создать разделитель?

Например, пусть будет прагматичный `<hr>`:

```
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="0"></div>
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="0"></div>
<hr>
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="1"></div>
<div class="task_wrapper" data-is_done="1"></div>
```

Вот код пузырька:

```
function sortTasks() {
  let wrap = document.querySelector('.adding_data_window');
  for (let i = 0; i < wrap.children.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < wrap.children.length; j++) {
      if (+wrap.children[i].getAttribute('data-is_done') > +wrap.children[j].getAttribute('data-is_done')) {
        replacedNode = wrap.replaceChild(wrap.children[j], wrap.children[i]);
        insertAfter(replacedNode, wrap.children[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function insertAfter(element, refElement) {
    return refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(element, refElement.nextSibling);
  }
}

// * выполнить эту функцию
// sortTasks();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: сделать отдельную функцию, которая **после сортировки** спокойно пройдётся циклом и поставит разделить перед первым по счёту элементом с единичкой (например с помощью метода `insertBefore`).

А вписывать ещё доп. функциональность в сортировку - неправильно.

---

А вообще тут и сама сортировка неправильна. В смысле - надо собрать данные массив, отсортировать и на основе массива что-то отрисовать или перерисовать. А так получается это не сортировка, а несколько операций в одном

Comment: Ваш вариант однозначно правильный и подталкивает к чистописанию в коде) Но все же могли бы вы отредактировать свой ответ и показать примерное решение? У меня получается паоставить разделитель ПОСЛЕ первого встреченного ```data-is_done="1"``` например ```wrp.appendChild(hr);```

Comment: А если использовать метод `insertBefore`?

Comment: да, сработало! Спасибо! Отредактируете ответ что бы я его пометил зеленой галочкой?

Comment: Не понял, зачем редактировать?

Comment: Думаю, если включить в ответ упоминание  ```insertBefore``` , другому пользователю (ищущему ответ) будет проще ориентироваться не спускаясь в комменты) Но галочка уже стоит)